# Transfer data from one datatable to another datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2015

I want to transfer data from one datatable to another . Like for example, for queue numbers, i have buttons for call, skip and enter. I want the data to transfer to another datatable when i press skip, and the queue number will go from the 'queue' datatable to 'missedQueue' datatable. But i do not know how to code it. Please help

Comment: Do we have to guess what database it is, and how the tables look like? Anyway, show us what you have tried as we are not here to do it for you.

Comment: the database i'm using is a local database in VS. the table have different columns like queue id, etc. Right now my code is string sql= String.Format("INSERT INTO missedQueue SELECT * FROM queue");  However when i pressed the skip button, it did not transfer the data

Comment: We still have to guess, you don't provide any code we can take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination table does not exist, the syntax is:

```
 SELECT * INTO missedQueue FROM queue
```